# converting image to base64 with data-uri with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, multer, cloudinary, data-uri

I successfully upload images with multer, store them in the local directory, save the path to the database. But since heroku does not save images in the local directory I have to upload images to Cloudinary but Cloudinary needs file to be converted to base64.

This is the implementation in node.js:

```js
const path = require("path");
const DataUri = require("datauri");

const dUri = new DataUri();

exports.dataUri = (file: Express.Multer.File): string =>
  dUri.format(path.extname(file.originalname).toString(), file.buffer);
```

I tried to implement this in typescript like this:

```js
import path from "path";
import DataUri from "datauri";
// here is cauinsg issue
const dUri = new DataUri();

export const dataUri = (file: Express.Multer.File): string =>
  dUri.format(path.extname(file.originalname).toString(), file.buffer);
```

in typescript implementation I am getting typescript error for `const dUri = new DataUri()` :

```
(alias) function DataUri(fileName: string, handler?: DataURI.Callback | undefined): Promise<string | undefined>

Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
index.d.ts(2, 31): An argument for 'fileName' was not provided.
'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I dont understand why `new DataUri()` works in olain node but not in typescript. I thought it would be ts file error so ignored it but it did not work. When I start the app I got this error:"  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined"

Instead of creating function, I tried to implement like this in the controller:

```
 const image = req.file;
  const file64=new DataUri(image.buffer)
```

this did not work neither

Comment: Why do you have to use base64?  There is a great deal of overhead this way.

Comment: Clodinary accepts base64 format

Comment: Cloudinary also accepts proper binary data:  https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference  Show the documentation where you see that they're requiring base64?  That'd be wild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution:

```
import DatauriParser from "datauri/parser";
const parser = new DatauriParser();
```

Since I use multer and store the image to memory, I get `req.file` and `req.file.buffer`

```
 const extName = path.extname(req.file.originalname).toString();
  const file64 = parser.format(extName, req.file.buffer);
```

Then

```
        const result = await Cloudinary.upload(file64.content!);
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I've worked with typescript just few times, but for alternative solution you can use this.
Before I've done base64 image upload with plain node.js using multer, and it worked well. I'll just leave here the actual part, so you can use for your needs (just edit there what you want):

**routes/product.js**

```
const productController = require('./controllers/product');
const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();
const multerUpload = require('./utilities/multer');

router.post('/form-data-upload', multerUpload.single('image'), productController.uploadFormDataImage);
router.post('/base64-upload', multerUpload.single('image'), productController.uploadBase64Image);

module.exports = router;
```

**controllers/product.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.APP_PORT;
const appUrl = process.env.APP_URL;

module.exports = {
    uploadFormDataImage: (req, res, next) => {
        return res.status(201).json({
            error: false,
            message: "Image was successfully uploaded.",
            url: `${appUrl}:${port}/images/${req.file.filename}`
        });
    },
    uploadBase64Image: async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const encoded = req.body.image;
            const base64ToArray = encoded.split(";base64,");
            const prefix = base64ToArray[0];
            const extension = prefix.replace(/^data:image\//, '');

            if (extension === 'jpeg' || extension === 'jpg' || extension === 'png')
            {
                const imageData = base64ToArray[1];
                const fileName = (new Date().getTime() / 1000|0) + '.' + extension;
                const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, './uploads/') + fileName;
                fs.writeFileSync(imagePath, imageData,  { encoding: 'base64' });

                return res.status(201).json({
                    error: false,
                    message: "Base64 Image was successfully uploaded.",
                    url: `${appUrl}:${port}/images/${fileName}`
                });
            }
            else {
                return res.status(403).json({
                    error: true,
                    message: "Base64 data not valid!",
                });
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            return res.status(403).json({
                error: true,
                message: e.message,
            });
        }
    },
};
```

**utilities/multer.js**

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            const filePath = path.join(__dirname, './uploads');
            cb(null, filePath);
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            const extension = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
            const fileName = (new Date().getTime() / 1000 | 0) + '.' + extension;
            cb(null, fileName);
        }
    }),
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10 // MB
    },
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        let valid = (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png');
        cb(null, valid);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a in build JS procedure to read a file in base64. For more details about [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

```
const fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = (data) => {
            console.log(data.target.result);
            // the result here will contain the base64 string.
        }

fr.readAsDataURL(file);
```